# Из БД MySQL в CSV формат

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите написать скрипт, который будет делать выборку некоторых элементов из БД и записывать данные в файл в CSV формате, или  хотя бы функцию которая распечатывает в файл?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
... 
$get_fileds = mysql_query('SELECT id, product_name, product_imgproduct_text FROM i_block_elements'); 
$f = fopen('file.csv', 'w'); 
while ($ar = mysql_fetch_row($get_fields)) 
  fputcsv($f, $ar); 
fclose($f); 
?>
```

Ну и сверху коннект к БД не забудь прописать, если чо:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect(«localhost», «jon», «secret»)
or die(«Could not connect to MySQL.»);
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: У меня есть БД _konsnew и в ней таблица i_block_elements , так вот из неё надо выбрать в файл только id, product_name, product_imgproduct_text объясните как плиз

Comment: SELECT t.id, t.product_name, t.product_imgproduct_text FROM i_block_elements t

Здесь все понятно?
Исправил ответ.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/konser0/public_html/import.php on line 13

Comment: Как я понимаю, проблема связана с отсутствием данных или таблиц в базе данных MySQL, перепишите запрос как в ответе без использования алиасов.

Comment: переписал, не помогает. выдает ошибку ту же. таблицы в базе есть, и данные тоже есть. логин, пасс все верно прописываю....=(

Comment: Можно увидеть кусок кода до 13 строк?

Answer (score 2):

Например:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'filename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM tablename;
```